# AccessDeniedHttpException is throw instead of redirect Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, redirect, roles, access-denied, authenticator

**I want to be redirected when the user do not have the admin role.** 
I try to set access on every page that have /users in the url. 
If the user is not connected the redirection is working but if I'm connected with **ROLE_USER** and I want to access /users page it's throw me an "Access Denied" Exception.

Packages/Security.yaml

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/users, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

AppAuthenticator

```
enter code here    <?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AppAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('username', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($username),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('homepage'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly there is an `onAuthenticationFailure` method that you can overwrite, similar to the `onAutheticationSuccess` that you are already overwriting. In that method you can return a (Redirect-)Response in case the authentication failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way there : 
 https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/access_denied_handler.html#customize-the-forbidden-response

I created

```
    <?php 
// src/Security/AccessDeniedHandler.php
namespace App\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authorization\AccessDeniedHandlerInterface;

class AccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException): ?Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login'));
    }
}
```

then added this in my security.yaml

```
 firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticator: App\Security\AppAuthenticator
        access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
```